# Removing values if they duplicate in two subsequent rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
dat <- data.frame(time = c(24.83,25.24,25.46,25.71,25.78,26.11), key = c("z","f","x","f","f","x"))
```

which looks like this:

```
time    key
24.83   z
25.24   f
25.46   x
25.71   f
25.78   f
26.11   x
```

I want to find all instances where the value of 'key' is the same in two subsequent rows (like 'f' here) and remove the second row.

I looked at ?duplicated and ?unique but still have no idea how to apply it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duplicated` and `unique` might not be the best choices here--they would remove all subsequent duplicates by default.

Instead, you can use `rle`, like this:

```
> dat[sequence(rle(as.character(dat$key))$lengths) == 1, ]
   time key
1 24.83   z
2 25.24   f
3 25.46   x
4 25.71   f
6 26.11   x
```

---

`rle` returns a `list` with two items: `lengths` (which indicates the run length) and `values`.

Comment: Thanks. It works, although I don't understand the bit with as.character(dat$key))$lengths. So if I'd like the function to ignore instances when 'z' duplicates in two subsequent rows, should I do dat[sequence(rle(as.character(dat[dat$key != "z", "key"]))$lengths) == 1, ] ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `diff`erent solution:

```
dat[-(which(diff(as.numeric(dat$key))==0)+1),]

   time key
1 24.83   z
2 25.24   f
3 25.46   x
4 25.71   f
6 26.11   x
```

Comment: +1 for your clever ab`use` of syntax highlighting :-)